# Absolute DIV taking all remaining height

Tags: html, css

I'm stacked with CSS, trying to give to an absolute positioned `<div>` the remaining height from where it starts.. Let me explain better with this snippet:

```css
#main {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

#child_1 {
  background-color: red;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  height: 100px; // this can vary
}

#child_2 {
  background-color: green;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  height: 77px; // this can vary
}

#child_3 {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="container">
  <div id="child_1">CHILD 1</div>
  <div id="child_2">CHILD 2</div>
  <div id="child_3">CHILD 3<br /> CHILD 3</div>
</div>
  
  <div id="something-else">
    Something that is <br />
    behind <br />
    the absoolute <br />
    div <br />
  </div>
  
</div>
```

As you can see, `div#child_3` starts right after `div#child_2` (this is a constraint, I do want this), and I also want it to be `position: absolute` because it must cover anything else that may be on the screen (basically, I will have a JS handler that show/hide `div#child_3`, and when it is shown, it should cover `#something-else`).

What I would like to achieve is that `div#child_3` takes all the height, from where it starts, to the end of the viewport.. To make it clearer, look at this image:
[image]

The difficult part is that.. I would like to achieve this only with CSS!
Because the only solution I've found so far is to set a fixed height to `div#child_3`, by granting him `(100vh - div#child_3.getBoundingBoundRect().Top)`, and setting a `ResizeObserver` to cover  the case in case in which the window got resized.
By the way, notice I cannot set a fixed `height: calc(100vh - 177px)` because, as written in CSS code, the `div#child_1` and `div#child_2` heights may vary.

Moreover, the `div#main` should not be touched: I can only work on `div#container` and its children, because they are part of a separate component (this example is simplified).

Comment: Hint: Use `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`.

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no reason for any of the children to have their position set to absolute then this layout could be achieved with flexbox. Please see the snippet below for an example:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  
  /* Important styles below */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
}

.child:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: red;
}

.child--large {
  /* Important styles below */
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="child child--large">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like for PatMan10 answer, `div.parent` cannot have `height: 100vh`: in my example, `div#main` also containing some other children (in the example, `div#something-else`), thus I cannot set its `height` to take full VP height

Comment: The 100vh was just for demonstration purposes, the large element will grow regardless of how it's parents height is set.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS flex-box. It's much more flexible and responsive than grid.

```css
#main {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
 }

#child_1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
 }

#child_2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#child_3 {
  background-color: lightBlue;
  flex-grow: 2;
 }
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="container">
  <div id="child_1">CHILD 1</div>
  <div id="child_2">CHILD 2</div>
  <div id="child_3">CHILD 3<br /> CHILD 3</div>
</div>
  
<div id="something-else">
  More<br>elements<br>down<br>here...
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work if I wouldn't have any other child in `div#main`. Instead, `div#main` will have other children (like in the example I made), and thus `div#main` cannot have `height: 100%`

Comment: OK, then make the `div#container` `height: 100vh` and leave `div#main` to wrap everything. Edited my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Thanks again for your time! Unfortunately, now the situation you achieve is the same as Huỳnh Lợi Nguyễn, where `div#something-else` is not covered by the `div#child_3`, but it's pushed all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** It seems the original answer I deliver below is not what you want. The another idea I come up with when try on my own local machine (instead of Stackoverflow's the snippet editor) is to wrap the `#child_3` inside another div called `#child_3_wrapper` and then position `#child_3` relative to `#child_3_wrapper` instead of `#container`.
Here is the full code:

```css
#main {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh; /*added this, try 100%, 98vh(or *padding:0;margin:0,...etc) to get the result desired*/ 
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr; /*added 1fr*/
}

#child_1 {
  background-color: red;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  height: 100px;
}

#child_2 {
  background-color: green;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  height: 77px; 
}

/* changed the code below */
#child_3_wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#child_3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* change top to 0 - relative to the wrapper, not the grid any more*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="child_1">CHILD 1</div>
    <div id="child_2">CHILD 2</div>
    <div id="child_3_wrapper">
      <div id="child_3">CHILD 3<br /> CHILD 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="something-else">
    Something that is <br />
    behind <br />
    the absoolute <br />
    div <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### The old answer

Is this what you want? I tried tweaking around with it to get the result.
Added `height: 100%;` to `#container` and `#child_3`

```css
#main {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%; /* add this */
  position: relative;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

#child_1 {
  background-color: red;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  height: 100px; // this can vary
}

#child_2 {
  background-color: green;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  height: 77px; // this can vary
}

#child_3 {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* add this */
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="child_1">CHILD 1</div>
    <div id="child_2">CHILD 2</div>
    <div id="child_3">CHILD 3<br /> CHILD 3</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="something-else">
    Something that is <br />
    behind <br />
    the absoolute <br />
    div <br />
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but both answers don't solve the problem. The second answer you gave almost solve it, but as you can see, `div#something-else` is pushed way down, when instead it should be covered by the `div#child_3` (or, in your example, by `div#child_3_wrapper`.